# Why do some websites showing 0 bytes in Chrome's developer tools

Tags: http, caching, chrome

I am doing a page speed optimization for my website and studying how other websites do it. I noticed that some websites such as as [Facebook](http://www.facebook.com/) or [Ringgitplus](http://www.ringgitplus.com/) show 0 bytes for some of their resources in Chrome's developer tools, Network tab, while the real content size is several kilobytes.

[image: The screenshot of Network tab showing 0 bytes for some resources]

I read some articles that says that *size* is the amount being fetched and *content* is the actual size of the response. So when size is 0 bytes, it means it served from cache. But the same thing happened when I open the page using Incognito or clearing all my cache.

How is this possible and how can I achieve the same thing for my websites?

Comment: and if you do a ctrl+F5 (a cache bypassing reload)

Comment: Have you profiled your page using http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/ yet?

Comment: @ratchetfreak It still the same.

Comment: @Marcel Yes, I am using several tools such as the one you mentioned, Google Page Speed, as well as webpagetest.org

Comment: Doesn't really answer the questions of why the uncached resrouces could possibly show 0b, but here's a good SO question which addresses the difference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072921/chrome-dev-tools-size-vs-content

Answer (score 4):

Understanding Chrome's behavior is easiest to see in a site that supports both *http* and *https*.

If you open Developer Tools and view [this image](http://www.google.com/images/nav_logo161.png), then Chrome reports 27.1k if the image is cached and 257 bytes if it is not. You can clear your cache inside Developer Tools by right-clicking on the area on the bottom of the screen (for example next to nav_logo161.png).

Now open the link with [https](https://www.google.com/images/nav_logo161.png). Chrome reports 0 bytes whether the item is cached or not. If it is cached you get a 304, and if it is not cached you see a 200 status. But you can see in the latency that the uncached response takes much longer.

So, long story short, if you want Chrome to report 0 bytes for your web-page use *https*.

This bug is recorded [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=189211) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=154706).

This bug is noticeable primarily when viewing images. The reason you notice it with the *http* links in the original post is that both sides actually render in *https*.